# NAV 2013 using .NET App

Tags: c#, dynamics-nav

I am looking to start a project for my company using NAV 2013.

I want to know if it is possible to develop a .Net application which can be linked into a clients page on NAV.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, maybe you want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help before start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to be more specific with the term "linked".
NAV 2013 does have .NET interoperability support, however that covers a few components;

1. .NET Client Add-ins
2. .NET Add-ins
3. Web Services
4. OData
5. Raw SQL

Options 1 and 2 would be appropriate for bringing enhanced .NET controls or logic into NAV.

Options 3 and 4 would suit if trying to access NAV data from within an external .NET application.

Option 5 is a "last resort" method, but you would directly query the database's tables from an external application. I'd only recommend reading data using this option, and not writing as it doesn't execute any NAV logic.

You may want to review the following MSDN article; [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh168247(v=nav.70).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh168247%28v=nav.70%29.aspx) which details these options (Ex. #5) with relevant examples for NAV 2013.

Comment: Thanks, this is the information I am after. Option 1 and 2 are what I am going to try out. Thanks again.

Comment: what do you men by `5. Raw SQL` anyway?

Comment: Directly querying the SQL tables behind NAV. This can be done using standard SQL libraries in .NET. I've clarified my answer to highlight that it's being accessed from an external application.

Comment: @ShadowXVII I have a .net .dll that we recently created to port some interop functionalities and other calculations. We want to use it in all NAV versions from 2013 onwards. Can you share with me some materials to refer when using a .net .dll in NAV? Can NAV use any .dll? My main worry is about compatibility and I want to know if we need to do anything in creating .dll in .net side to make sure that it can be used in NAV.

Comment: Hi @bonCodigo, you're best starting a fresh question, rather than comments on other questions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh168247%28v=nav.71%29.aspx is what you're looking for. Yes, NAV can pretty much use any DLL, and your DLL doesn't need to upgraded between versions.